# Block border + text border of different color in CSS

Tags: css, text, border

I'm trying to achieve this in CSS:

[image]

I would like the green line to always be the width of the text (no fixed width). I have a constraint, the tex is contained in an H3 tag with no ability to add a span tag inside it.

Comment: Is there a container for the `h3` element (say, a `div` element with `class`) that we can use, or can such an element be added? If not, I’m afraid there is no CSS solution (since there is no selector that would match the text content). But you don’t need extra elements in the markup if it is OK to add them with client-side JavaScript.

Comment: It is possible with just one `h3` tag but would need something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5oe993qq/1/). Would you be able to do it? The `h3` can also have some text but that can be hidden with a transparent color font.

Comment: @Harry nice one.. I think this should be an answer.

Comment: @Mr_Green: Not sure if OP can add that extra attribute mate. Also target browsers is an issue if IE 7 etc needs to be supported (as pseudo-elements don't work there).

Comment: @Sebastien: Did any of these attempts come close to giving you a solution mate?

Answer (score 2):

you could maybe try this aproach also:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <h3>RECENT EPISODES</h3>    
</div>


.container {
    width:100%; 
    position:relative;
}
h3 {
    display:inline-block;
    border-bottom:1px solid green;
    padding-bottom:10px; 
    margin:0;
    position:relative;

}
.line {
    height:1px;
    background-color:#ededed;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/az6pr1mz/

Answer (score 0):

### Update:

I missed that you don't need `span` inside the `h3`. I added a workaround. I am not sure whether this is the only solution. But I think it can be improved though. In the below code, I am using css content property to hide the border of the container.

NOTE: Use as many dots `.` as you can use to make it work on all resolutions.

**CSS**

```
.container {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    word-break: break-all;
}
.container:after {
    content:"....................................................................................................................";
    color: transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid green;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/squa33uu/3/)**

Comment: There is no reason to change `h3` to `div`. The issue is how to refer to the text as an element, and just using `span` inside `h3` is a simpler change than the one applied here.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela yeah seems I was confused somewhere.. I read just now in w3c that h3 allows phrasing elements. So, updated and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The grey line needs to go on a block level tag while the green needs to go on an inline tag. This means that you need two nested tags for it to work and that you must either add a `span` inside the `h3` or a `div` surrounding it. An `h3` can always be made inline if needed.

A slightly different approach would be to add the secondary element outside the `h3` without surrounding it and position that so it lies directly under the `h3`.

In any case, you will need a minimum of two elements for the borders to cling to.

Answer (score -1):

For example this code: (is clearly and not uses absolute positions)

HTML:

```
<h3><span>Recent episodes</span></h3>
```

CSS:

```
h3{
    text-transform:uppercase;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}

h3 span{
    display:inline-block;
    border-bottom:1px solid #080;
    margin:0 0 -1px 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tp0nnapu

Comment: The question says that no `span` can be added.